# Как в PHP создавать динамически страницы типа site.com/page и так далее? Чтобы не выводило ошибку Страница не найдена?

Tags: php

Как в PHP создавать динамически страницы типа test.ru/page и так далее? Чтобы не выводило ошибку Страница не найдена?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь как таковой PHP ни при чём.
В .htacces отправляете запрос в index.php, а вот там уже строите логику обработки параметров
Как пример

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Данная возможность называется роутингом, почти во всех современных фреймворках да и вообще в любой **MVC** архитектуре, используется маршрутизация(роутинг).

Так что же такое **роутинг**?

Все проще чем кажется, это настройка веб-сервера так, чтобы все прилетающие запросы обрабатывал один или более обработчиков, не важно будет там запрос типа `url/verniMmeZaraza/MoyStranitsu?da=tochno!`, запрос будет обрабатывать все равно одна точка входа, например `index`, а потом уже уже скрипт будет вызывать другие процессы и вообще обрабывать запрос. Просто вам надо запомнить — **файлов на сервер не существует, все виртуально, все отдаёт сервер**, и вы можете абсолютно сто процентно настроить веб-сервер так, чтобы он отдавал что-либо хоть на такой запрос `yaVasya!`.

**Примеры**.

Настроим наш сервер с помощью `.htaccess` Так чтобы все запросы летели на `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

А теперь собственно в **index.php** настроим ответ только на URL `vasya`.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'sitename.com/vasya') 
{
    echo "You Vasya";
} else {
    echo "404 page";
}
```